# Installing Ubuntu on native ZFS root with encryption

Tags: grub2, system-installation, encryption, zfs

I'm trying to install Ubuntu with a native ZFS root filesystem on top of an encrypted partition. The device setup is as follows:

- The physical disk is partitioned into a small boot partition and the rest.
- The rest of the disk is entirely encrypted and carved up into a `/swap` and a `/root` partition for the actual system.
- The ZFS pool created on that root partition with a couple of ZFS filesystems for things like `/home`.

These are the two principal guides I've been following:

- [HOWTO-install-Ubuntu-to-a-Native-ZFS-Root-Filesystem](https://github.com/zfsonlinux/pkg-zfs/wiki/HOWTO-install-Ubuntu-to-a-Native-ZFS-Root-Filesystem)
- [EncryptedFilesystemLVMHowto](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EncryptedFilesystemLVMHowto)

It's all working fine except for the final step -- the installation of grub. `update-grub` says (inside the `chroot`)

```
error: cannot find a device for / (is /dev mounted?)
```

`/dev` is mounted and I followed the additional advice in the second guide for setting up `/etc/default/grub` and so on.

I can't seem to get grub to recognise the device and `grub.cfg` and `menu.lst` are not being created. Are there any steps I might have missed? All of this is running inside VirtualBox if that's relevant.

In particular I'm wondering what the correct grub command-line would be to boot this system.

Comment: Most of these solutions are outdated. For Ubuntu 20.04 use the official guide: https://openzfs.github.io/openzfs-docs/Getting%20Started/Ubuntu/Ubuntu%2020.04%20Root%20on%20ZFS.html

Answer (score 1):

Grub 1.99 (shipped with Ubuntu) doesn't support encrypted zfs, which is why update-grub is failing.

So your options are:

1. Install grub 2.00 (which does support encrypted zfs).
2. Write your grub.cfg manually rather than using update-grub.

Both of these options deviate significantly from Ubuntu defaults, but still much less so than using encrypted ZFS for your root FS in the first place :)

For #1 you'll need to compile grub 2.00 from source, as I'm not aware of any grub 2.00 packages for Ubuntu.

For #2 you'll need to dpkg-divert update-grub and replace it with a symlink to /bin/true then write your grub.cfg by hand (updating it whenever you get a kernel upgrade).

If you need to more specifics on how to do either option I'd be glad to expand on that.

Comment: The zfs-supporting grub is provided by a ppa (mentioned in the first guide). I've tried ZFS without encryption (i.e. following just the first guide) and that works fine. The problem is really just that I don't know the combination of grub commandline options and initrd configuration to make the combination of encryption + zfs succeed.

Comment: That PPA includes grub with ZFS support, not with encrypted ZFS support. For encrypted ZFS you need grub 2.00.

Comment: Ahh, I see. I'll give that a try.

Comment: I've tried compiling grub 2.00 from source but the machine froze up while I did that. I might give it another go later, but this definitely doesn't inspire me with confidence. I'll probably just wait until ZFS on linux is more stable.

Comment: I've tried with Ubuntu 12.10 which comes with grub 2.00, but that didn't work either -- same error as before. Apparently there are some changes about to be made to the zfs-related packages though, so it might work in a while.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to bind the LVM root. Exit the chroot, and type:

```
sudo mount --bind /dev /mnt/root/dev
```

Then chroot back in, and see if the ZFS-grub update works.

Comment: I did this. It's in the first guide I linked to.

Comment: But did you bind your physical root and not the ZFS root?

Comment: Yes. Exactly as you said, before entering the chroot.

Comment: This step what does it give you: 

6.1 Verify that the ZFS root filesystem is recognized by GRUB:

# grub-probe /
zfs

Comment: It gives me the same error about not being able to find a device.